# How can I suggest new tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Hi all, I am not still have enough privileges to create new tags in this not meta site. Is there any way to suggest new tags to anyone who have enough privileges?
The new tags I suggest are: floating point arithmetic or floating point operations.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flag a question for moderator attention if you think it requires a new tag and you lack the rep to create a new tag -- simply click the "flag" link.

Comment: @perterstone, I will be notified the moment I log in and take care of it. You can also put a comment on your question, "can someone please add the tag 'Tag_name'?" and people in general will help you out.

Answer (score 2):

150 rep is required to create tags. You'll get there right away! It may be bumped up to 1500 once the site graduates, however.

I, too, read [your question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/9314/2118) and thought it could use a [floating-point](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) tag. Anyone else agree?

Comment: this is only true on Stack Overflow due to extreme size; on "normal" sites the new tag threshold is 200 see http://superuser.com/faq#reputation